# How to test a component HSL background color in cypress? ( Typescript )

Tags: reactjs, cypress, value-of-css-property

I'm using a CSS module for my styling, and I want to test the background color of the button, but it's in hsl not RGB.

I have seen people struggle with the same issue, but they found solutions like chai-color or color libraries. The problem is I use Typescript and these libraries does not support types. How can I test my HSL background?

```
 it("when button rendered with type primary, should have blue color hsl(206, 100%, 42%)", () => {
    cy.mount(
      <Button
        text="Blue"
        type="primary"
      />
    );
    cy.get("button").should(
      "have.css",
      "background-color",
      "hsl(206, 100%, 42%)"
    );
  });
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/03/17/how-to-test-an-application-that-changes-css-variable/ this might be helpful link for your test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this which could be useful [30secondsofcode - RGB to HSL](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/rgb-to-hsl/).

The issue with CSS values in tests is rounding, so you may want to use `closeTo` matching

```js
const RGBToHSL = (r, g, b) => {
  r /= 255;
  g /= 255;
  b /= 255;
  const l = Math.max(r, g, b);
  const s = l - Math.min(r, g, b);
  const h = s
    ? l === r
      ? (g - b) / s
      : l === g
      ? 2 + (b - r) / s
      : 4 + (r - g) / s
    : 0;
  return [
    60 * h < 0 ? 60 * h + 360 : 60 * h,
    100 * (s ? (l <= 0.5 ? s / (2 * l - s) : s / (2 - (2 * l - s))) : 0),
    (100 * (2 * l - s)) / 2,
  ];
}

cy.get("button")
  .should($el => {
    const rgbString = window.getComputedStyle($el[0])
      .getPropertyValue("background-color")           // "rgb(0, 121, 214)"

    const rgbValues = rgbString.match(/rgb\([.*]\)/)[1]
                               .split(', ').map(v => +v)   // [0, 121, 214]

    const hsl = RGBToHSL(...rgbValues)

    expect(hsl[0]).to.be.closeTo(206, 1)
    expect(hsl[1]).to.be.closeTo(100, 1)
    expect(hsl[2]).to.be.closeTo(42, 1)
  })
```

Comment: I converted my HSL to RGB using an online tool and I used it as const for testing. Am I faking the test? I see RGBTOHSL will do the same.

Comment: IMO converting manually is fine - it's just testing with different units. I was going to suggest that initially, but the calculation approach looked interesting. It would also be useful if you were obtaining the HSL value from say an API.

Comment: BTW `const rgbString = $el.attr('background-color')` seems wrong on 2nd look, since you have no such attribute. It should be using `getComputedStyle()`.